# The user profile service failed on login

Tags: windows-7

Pc came loaded with windows 7. I dont not have a dvd to boot from. How can i login? (There is only one profile account, mine).

Answer (score 0):

did you try pressing "F8" during the time between the bios boot and windows boot to load in safe mode and use administrator as the user name?

Comment: yes thats what i am doing now hopefully it works

Comment: If you get logged into W7 again, make a System Repair Disc, All Programs Menu>Maintenance>Create a System Repair Disc. Also see this thread http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistasecurity/thread/4ed66b21-c23e-42f1-98b2-706dcf931fae